# Equivalent method to IHttpRequest::NegotiateClientCertificate in an ASP.NET module

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, ihttpmodule, iis-modules

What method can be called by an IIS ASP.NET module that is equivalent to the IHttpRequest::NegotiateClientCertificate method in the IIS Native-Code Extensibility Web Server Core API?

In other words, in an IIS native module, the method IHttpRequest::NegotiateClientCertificate in the IIS Native-Code Extensibility Web Server Core API initiates client certificate negotiation with a Web client. What method can be called in an IIS ASP.NET module to initiate client certificate negotiation with a Web client after receiving the request?

Comment: you could use this code to set the SSL Negotiate flag in iis : `
         ConfigurationSection clientCertificateMappingAuthenticationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/clientCertificateMappingAuthentication", "Default Web Site");
         clientCertificateMappingAuthenticationSection["enabled"] = true;

         ConfigurationSection accessSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/access", "Default Web Site");
         accessSection["sslFlags"] = @"Ssl, SslNegotiateCert";`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/clientcertificatemappingauthentication refer this link for more detail

Comment: @Jalpa-Panchal , I am quite aware of the SSL Negotiate flag. However, I cannot use it my case because the module initiates client certificate negotiation with a Web client only sometimes. The module decides whether to initiate client certificate negotiation with a Web Client based on the request so it has to be able to receive the request prior to deciding to initiate client certificate negotiation with a web client.